# ASC-GZIP decoding in Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, gzip

I've been scouring the internet for a library or piece of code that will help me decompress an XFDL file with this type of encoding:application/x-xfdl;content-encoding="asc-gzip". All of the previous XFDL files I've dealt with have had this type of encoding: application/vnd.xfdl;content-encoding="base64-gzip", and I've had no problem using Base64 and GZIP (both libraries on github written by nicklockwood).  I've found code in Python that would decompress these types of files, located here:http://www.ourada.org/blog/archives/375, but I'm at a loss as to how I would implement this code into an Objective-C project.

Any help at all or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asc-gzip` examples I have found are actually zlib, then base-64 encoded.  It is broken into blocks, with each block preceded by the compressed and uncompressed length in big-endian order, two bytes for each.

So to decode:

1. Base-64 decode the whole thing.  Then on the decoded bytes:
2. Compute the next compressed length from the first two bytes in big-endian order.  Call
   it *c*.
3. Compute the next uncompressed length from the next two
   bytes in big-endian order.  Call it *u*.
4. Use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to decode the zlib stream consisting
   of the next *c* bytes. Verify that zlib decoded exactly *c* bytes, and that the resulting uncompressed data is exactly *u*
   bytes long.
5. Repeat starting at step 2 until the data is consumed. 
   (It should all be exactly consumed.)

Interestingly, both "`asc`" and "`gzip`" are misnomers in the encoding name.  `asc` really means base 64, and `gzip` really means zlib.  Go figure.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with big-endian and byte processing in XCode. I've been reading up on the Core Endian Reference, but i'm going cross-eyed. Do you have any code for iOS that would help? Thanks so much for your answer so far!

Comment: To read two bytes in big-endian order, simply read the first byte as an unsigned 8-bit integer (unsigned char), multiply it by 256, then add the second byte as an unsigned 8-bit integer.  Voilà.

Comment: @jimmybondy Nope.